# Select the max number of repeated records in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

If I have multiple records in a SQL table like:

```
name                score
...................................
sami                55
ali                 140
sami                60
```

I want to select the highest score for each player.
The expected result would be:

```
ali ,140
sami, 60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is as simple as that:

```
SELECT name, MAX(score) FROM <table_name> GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select name,max(score) as 'Highest Score' from gametable group by name;
```